# Enable/disable Optimus/Enduro in cross platform manner

Tags: opengl, opencl, optimus

In order to save power it is common in recent graphics architectures to dynamically switch between a discrete high-performance and an integrated lower-performance GPU, where the high-performance GPU is only enabled when the need for extra performance is present.

This technology is branded as [nvidia Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) and [AMD Enduro](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/enduro) for the two main GPU vendors.

However due to the non-standardized way in which these technologies work, managing them from a developer's perspective can be a nightmare. For example in [this PDF](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf) from nvidia on the subject, they explain the many intricacies, limitations and pitfalls that you will have to worry about as a developer to manage nvidia Optimus on just one platform.

As an example, in the linked PDF above, the following is a tip for selecting GPU on Windows:

```
extern "C" {
 _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

However that will only work for nvidia GPUs on Windows platform. What would be the equivalent for AMD/Intel on OSX/Linux, and on AMD hardware?

So in more detail my question is, how can I

1. Detect the presence of Optimus/Enduro and possibly other dynamically=switching GPU architectures programmatically?
2. Select which of the GPUs should be enabled programmatically?
3. Do so in a manner that is cross-platform over all relevant platforms?
4. Do so in a manner that works together with all technologies that might use GPU such as DX/OpenGL/Vulkan/OpenCL/CUDA/Qt?

I am working with C++14/Qt5.7 codebase under Ubuntu 16.04-amd64 using nVidia hardware.